# Using the Internet in a mobile Flex application

Tags: flash, apache-flex, adobe

I am building a mobile Flex application, and I need to access the internet during my program in order to return some data in a pdf file.

First of all, I want the application to use the internet in the background. So, I do NOT want the app to transfer to the web browser.

Also, my app allows the user to enter certain information, which will be needed to access the website i.e. username and password. I want this information to be entered automatically without the user going to the website and entering the information.

Lastly, is there a way I can get the information off of the pdf file, or do I have to return the entire file to the user?

As you can probably see, I am extremely confused about how to access the internet with my specific requirements. I have heard about HTTPService and navigateToUrl... but I don't know which is more suitable for my conditions.

Thanks for all of your help (this is my first Flex program) :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use to switch from your app or something, use simple URLLoaders and load the page in the background.

Comment: Does the URLLoader load the page in the background automatically? If not, could you please elaborate or kindly point me to a website that clearly explains URLLoaders?

Comment: URLLoader loads a given URL in the background and notifies you with Event.COMPLETE.. then you have access to the data that was downloaded.

Comment: Does this include a pdf file? Because I have read that Flex allows text, html, etc. only.

Comment: It can be anything. I've used it to load all sorts of URLs.

Comment: Actually one last question, if you don't mind. Is it possible to use data-binding in a url?

Comment: What do you mean? You can send query/POST parameters, like to send username and password

Comment: var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("https://www.google.com/"{myList.selectedItem.number}"/"{new Date().fullYear}"/"{new Date().monthUTC}"("{new Date().day}")/"{new Date().monthUTC}"-"{new Date().day}"/"{myList.selectedItem.number}"D"{new Date().monthUTC}{new Date().fullYear}"DAILYREP_.PDF");

Comment: https://www.google.com/9642/2012/06(Jun)/06-22/9642D062012DAILYREP_.PDF where google is my website

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12830/discussion-between-user1193587-and-karthik-kumar-viswanathan)